# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3'

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that sums everything in a space delimited list. Here is my code so far:

```
n=int(input())
petals=[0]*n
for i in range(n):
    petals[i]=int(input())
total=0
for i in range(n):
    total+=petals[i]
print(total)
```

This works when I input one number at a time, but I want to be able to enter `1 2 3` and have it print `6`.
When I do that, I get the error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3'.

How can I change this program to use `1 2 3`?

Comment: Works fine for me, what are you inputting into it? Edit: i just saw that you are inputting '1 2 3', meanwhile you should input each number separately.

Comment: This code expects only one number per input.  You can't enter `1 2 3` all at once as you did.

Comment: No but like how do you make it so that there is one line that contains N space-separated integers petals1…petalsN.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to input something like `1 2 3`, you could split the string into a list of numbers:

```py
petals = input("Input numbers seperated by a space: ").strip().split()
total=0
for i in range(len(petals)):
    total+=int(petals[i])
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're entering three numbers as one input '1, 2 and 3' rather than as three individual numbers? '1', '2' and '3'?

Also note that you can calculate the sum of elements in a list with numbers easier using Python's built-in sum() function.
So rather than writing:

```
total=0
for i in range(n):
    total+=petals[i]
```

You could simply write:

```
total = sum(petals)
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers from @robbo and @Shar, you could split the input on whitespace, convert to integers and print:

```
print(sum([int(x) for x in input("Input numbers separated by a space: ").strip().split()]))
```